# Python mechanize login to website

Tags: python, webforms, mechanize

I'm trying to log into a website using Python and Mechanize, however, I'm running into trouble when trying to get the POST data to behave as I want.

Essentially I want to replicate this using mechanize and Python:

```
wget --quiet --save-cookies cookiejar --keep-session-cookies --post-data "action=login&login_nick=USERNAME&login_pwd=PASSWORD" -O outfile.htm http://domain.com/index.php
```

The form looks like this:

```
<login POST http://domain.com/index.php application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(login_nick=USERNAME)>
  <PasswordControl(login_pwd=PASSWORD)>
  <CheckboxControl(login_auto=[1])>
  <SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>>
```

Setting the appropriate values and submitting the form isn't a problem, but that leaves out the "action=login"-part.

```
response = self.browser.open(self.url+"/index.php")
self.browser.select_form(name="login")

self.browser["login_nick"] = self.encoded_username
self.browser["login_pwd"] = self.encoded_password

self.browser.method = "POST"

response = self.browser.open(self.browser.submit())

print (response.read())
```

**Now the question is, how do I add the `action=login` part?**

Edit: Okay, so I added a hidden field named *action* and set the value to *login*. Analyzing the TCP stream with Wireshark, the POST data is indeed structured the way it should. However, it seems that mechanize is messing with my urlencoding (I have already urlencoded the values specifically for the charset that the website uses). For example, my username contains an Å - which I have urlencoded to %C5. However, when it's sent with mechanize, it's displayed as %25C5.
**How do I stop mechanize from changing the strings?**

EDIT: I realized that rather than fighting mechanize, I could just **not** urlencode my strings before sending them. Case closed.

Comment: Instead of editing your question and adding the answer to the question body, you should post an answer to your own question and then accept it. It's more *natural* this way.

Comment: I did. I just can't accept it for another 2 days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mechanize seems to urlencode the strings anyway, so there's no point in fighting it. This is the final solution (obviously not syntactically valid, but hopefully you get the idea).

```
import mechanize

self.browser = mechanize.Browser()
self.browser.open(self.url)
self.browser.select_form(name="login")

self.browser["login_nick"] = self.username
self.browser["login_pwd"] = self.password
self.browser.new_control("HIDDEN", "action", {})
control = self.browser.form.find_control("action")
control.readonly = False
self.browser["action"] = "login"
self.browser.method = "POST"
self.browser.action = self.url

response = self.browser.submit()
```