# Mechanize and Beautiful soup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm trying to submit a form to a site using beautiful soup and mechanize.

Mechanize on its own throws an error with nested forms so I tried following the suggestion of using another parser. 
Here's the code:

```
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US;      rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    response = browser.open('URL')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.get_data())
    response.set_data(soup.prettify())
    browser.set_response(response)
```

However I'm getting the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: `'ascii'` codec can't encode character `u'\xbb'` in position 2006: ordinal not in range(128)

for this line of code : `response.set_data(soup.prettify())`

I'm not quite sure what error being thrown is here if its a problem with types ?

Comment: The problem is that you've got non-ASCII characters, but you're trying to encode to ASCII somewhere. First, break that line into two pieces to see which is the problem: `pretty = soup.prettify()`, then `response.set_data(pretty)`, and see which one fails. Then give us the traceback, not just the error description.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/scripts/Machine.py", line 52, in <module>
    response.set_data(pretty)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg/mechanize/_response.py", line 288, in set_data
    cache.write(data)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbb' in position 2006: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: thanks for the reply, it appears the problem is in the set_data function? so a problem with the the encoding?

Comment: try: `response.set_data(soup.prettify(encoding='latin-1'))` and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @Jsk: Sorry for making you go through all these steps and then responding for hours, but… First, I assume you're on Python 2.x, not 3.x? Second, if you are, try `print type(prettify)` and see if it's `unicode` or `str`. If it's `unicode`, try encoding it explicitly (e.g., `pretty_utf8 = prettify.encode('utf-8')` then `response.set_data(pretty_utf8)`). If the HTTP headers specify a charset, use whatever they specify instead of `utf-8`.

Comment: @abarnert: I appreciate the help, 
first I'm on 2.7, second after encoding it utf8 its a string and they specify utf-8 
it no longer throws up that error so the encoding work although I'm still receiving my original parsing error of nested FORMS which I'm confused about as I though using a different parser might work? 
Would I be best to try another method and pass it back to mechanize as I did with beautifulsoup or is there something else I'm missing? 
is it just a parsing error of the https page?

Comment: By "original parsing error", do you mean the `UnicodeEncodeError`, or is there something else wrong? If the latter, please give us the traceback. And either way, it would really be helpful if you could give us the HTTP document if you want us to help debug parsing it.

Comment: I agree with @abarnert. It would be easier for us to help you debug your problem if you give us the html or at least dummy html with same structure. I know you're new to Python, however, I don't understand why you're trying to submit forms this way. Check this SO post [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896894/using-mechanize-to-login-to-a-webpage) for a simple example of form submission and then you can refer to [article](http://stockrt.github.com/p/emulating-a-browser-in-python-with-mechanize/) for excellent explanation on how to emulate browser behavior using Mechanize. HTH.