# ParseError: nested FORMs

Tags: python, mechanize, nested-forms

Python mechanize gives nested FORMs error for this code:

```
url = 'http://bis.zju.edu.cn/psi/'
browse = mechanize.Browser()
browse.set_handle_robots(False)
browse.open(url)

# print [n for n in browse.forms()]
# ParseError: nested FORMs

browse.select_form(name="form1") # or (nr=0)
# ParseError: nested FORMs

seq = '>seq1' + '\n' + 'MNANSSAKLGDSA'
browse['sequence'] = seq
response = browse.submit()
```

---

Neither this solves:

```
browse = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
browse.set_handle_robots(False)
browse.open(url)

print [n for n in browse.forms()]
# [] # empty list

browse.select_form(name="form1") # or (nr=0)
# FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'form1'
```

---

Nor this:

```
browse = mechanize.Browser()
browse.set_handle_robots(False)
response = browse.open(url)
# 'modify response' (anyway? to remove erroneous html?)
browse.set_response(response)

print [n for n in browse.forms()]
# [] # empty list

browse.select_form(name="form1") # or (nr=0)
# FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'form1'
```

---

I have searched net for Q/A on nested forms error in python/mechanize in stackoverflow/ other forums. No solutions.

Any (quick) help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135964/submitting-nested-form-with-python-mechanize), and possibly try using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the website instead of mechanize itself, BS is a little bit more robust.

Comment: Thanks @Nee. Looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135964/submitting-nested-form-with-python-mechanize. Parsing with BS does not solve the nested FORMs problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204372/mechanize-and-beautiful-soup-python/40759022#40759022 yet. Trying ...