# Python Https Request

Tags: python, authentication, https, login-script

I am trying to login on a website, but am having trouble do so. I have read various solutions, but where I am struggling is how do you know the login data form?

For example, in this solution:

```
def main():
# Start a session so we can have persistant cookies
session = requests.session()
# This is the form data that the page sends when logging in
login_data = {
    'Name': Name,
    'Password': Password,
    'Log In': 'Log In'
}
# Authenticate
r = session.post(URL, data=login_data)
```

How do you know the login data is in that form? I would appreciate help in finding some reading on the requests.session class and how/what it does with login_data.

Every solution I've tried just brings up the source of the webpage saying that I need to be logged in to access it.

Let me know if anything was unclear

CHEERS

Comment: First: for the most part, the session documentation will only tell you how `session.post` is different from `requests.post`, and you're expected to look at the `requests.post` documentation to figure out the rest.

Comment: Meanwhile: The way you know what form a website expects is to read the documentation on that website. If there is no documentation, you need to experiment with it—use the browser interface or the official client or whatever they have and watch what it sends. What site are you trying to connect to? Do they have a published web API? How did you know to send parameters with those three names?

Comment: @abarnert thanks. yeah I'm looking at the documentation now. They site I am trying to access is only used internally in my company. They don't have a published web API. As for the send parameters, they are just place holders. How would I watch what it sends?

Comment: Most web browsers nowadays have a "Develop" or similarly-named menu or submenu, either built-in or as one of the top-10 add-ons, that opens up a panel where you can do things like record all queries. (If you can't figure that out, you can always set up a simple proxy between the browser and the server, but it's generally easier to do these things from within the browser nowadays.)

Comment: Meanwhile, if it's an internal corporate site… can't you just ask the people who maintain it?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) when dealing with forms on the web. You simply need to create a Browser() object and start navigating the site, sometimes you need to include a cookie jar to handle cookies.

As far as being informed what the field names of the form are, I recommend going through the source code of the HTML page you are trying to log into. You could also use mechanize to iterate through all the forms in a site and print each field value.

[Here you have an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896894/using-mechanize-to-login-to-a-webpage) of how to deal with forms in mechanize.

Luck !

Comment: The problem I run into is that the login page is a pop up so the browser will not let me view the html source.