# Excel VBA website login stalls after "redirect"

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I ultimately want to use Excel VBA with InternetExplorer to scrape data from a webpage.

The scenario requires login to one website page that then redirects to another page where another data entry is required to trigger the response containing the data that I ultimately want.

My code (redacted) successfully performs the initial login and reaches the redirected page, but it stalls before making the data entry on that page.  I do not receive any error notification.

I haven't been able to find an answer to the stall, but I assume it is somehow related to the website page redirection.  As a point of interest, if I omit the Application.Wait, the execution tries to use the ("name").Value following it in first phase of the login.  If anyone can explain that also, I'd be very interested.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "http://something/Login.aspx"
Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
IE.document.getElementById("name").Value = "signin"
IE.document.getElementById("password").Value = "pword"
IE.document.getElementById("btnValidate").Click
Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
'Now at redirected page
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:08"))
'This is where execution stalls
IE.document.getElementById("name").Value = "identification"
IE.document.getElementById("btnValidate").Click
```

Comment: I would suggest to debug it by outputting last readystate, and if it's 4, it may be possible that page is dynamic (content is loaded via ajax) and you elements simply don't exist yet, so you get an error on this line `IE.document.getElementById("name").Value = "identification"`, in javascript you would get something like `can not change property 'value' of undefined` or similar, that's where execution is being halted... easiest solution? put `IE.document.getElementById("name").Value` into while loop, and act on it only after  the actual object is being returned

Comment: You might be better off using existing libraries to handle all these steps instead of re-inventing the wheel. I recommend using Python with the WebDriver library to parse the webpage. You can then make Excel output from Python and even pass off to a VBA module for Excel post-processing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387896/8173870

Comment: Can you please confirm that other page got opened in the same tab and it does not get open in a new tab? If that page get open in a new tab than your code will fail to find the control. Other thing you can try to wait for some more time. It can be possible that page is taking more time to get load.

Comment: Flash Thunder comment got me looking at/thinking about asynchronous effects of using VBA linking to any other program which then linked to web page.

Comment: Flash Thunder comment got me looking at/thinking about asynchronous effects of using VBA linking to any other program which then linked to web page and various unknown timeouts.  HackSlash was interesting but totally ignored the questions I was asking.  In answer to Deepak, page was opening in the same tab.  After considering everything (particularly the asynchronous impacts), I'm abandoning this code and reworking the problem using HTML - to avoid the middleman (the Browser).  Thanks for the comments, however.