# Using Mechanize to Login

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to login using the library Mechanize. This the output i get when i run

```
for f in br.forms():
    print f
```

OUTPUT

```
  <login_form1 POST https://www.box.com/login application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(login=)>
  <PasswordControl(password=)>
  <HiddenControl(_pw_sql=) (readonly)>
  <CheckboxControl(remember_login=[*on])>
  <HiddenControl(__login=1) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(reg_step=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(submit1=1) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(folder=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(skip_framework_login=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(login_or_register_mode=login) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(new_login_or_register_mode=) (readonly)>
  <SubmitControl(<None>=) (readonly)>>
<google_apps_login_form POST https://www.box.com/sso/google_apps application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(google_apps_domain=Enter Domain Name)>
  <CheckboxControl(google_apps_non_enterprise=[on])>>
```

Now to Login to the page i do,

```
br.form['login']='USERNAME'
br.form['password']='PASSWORD'
```

But still the response shows that i havent logged in.

Am i going wrong somewhere ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225721/python-mechanize-login-to-website Linked question has a nicer solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well from the looks of it you're missing `br.submit()` (it seems you didn't skip `br.select_form(nr=0)`, login form). Only after you would be logged in. Basically you just filled in your username and password, but didn't press enter.

Comment: @VinodK: If everything worked out and no follow-ups accept it please.